# In protractor "chrome not reachable" error coming

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, protractor

my machine is windows 7, chrome is latest with 32 bit, below is conf.js

```
 exports.config = {
    // directConnect:true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],

  capabilities:  {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'binary': 'D:/chromedriver.exe',
  }   },
};
```

when i run above conf.js below error comes

```
    [21:37:58] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:37:58] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[21:39:02] E/launcher - chrome not reachable


[21:39:02] E/launcher - WebDriverError: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c581090
6a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide a
ny stacktrace information)

[21:39:02] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

below is selenium server starting log,its 32 bit machine with basic code for protractor

```
    webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[22:39:26] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\Yogi\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.32.exe -Dwebdriver.
gecko.driver=C:\Users\Yogi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\se
lenium\geckodriver-v0.18.0.exe -jar C:\Users\Yogi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port 4444
[22:39:26] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 6016
22:39:38.385 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b
'
22:39:38.401 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-09-14 22:39:39.174:INFO::main: Logging initialized @11199ms to org.selenium
hq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
22:39:40.463 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
22:39:41.354 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDrive
r registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform
=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA
22:39:42.073 INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler
2017-09-14 22:39:42.862:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2017-09-14 22:39:43.354:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.S
ervletContextHandler@1784306{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for pat
h: /
2017-09-14 22:39:43.448:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletC
ontextHandler@1784306{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-09-14 22:39:49.823:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnecto
r@95a785{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-09-14 22:39:49.823:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @21844ms
22:39:49.823 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Comment: Your WIndows 7 is 32bit?  from your conf.js,  you set slenium address to local server, could you paster  selenium start log and log during your code running from the command window which running the selenium server.

Comment: yes its 32 bit windows 7, added selenium start log, once it started no lof generating thereafter

Comment: can you confirm this file exist: C:\Users\Yogi\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.32.exe  and can you execute the chromedriver_2.32.exe  from command line?

Comment: If above two things are correct after confirm,  one possbile reason is your chrome browser not installed in the defaut path which Selenium think it should to be. one default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome, another is C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome

Comment: Thanks Yong, it launched with C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome this path..below is conf.js  for other people  exports.config = {
 // directConnect:true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
  
  capabilities:  {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'binary': 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
  }   },
};

Comment: So both remove chromeOptions or keep it with the correct path report same error. If so, the last option it's to try change selenium-standalone, chromedriver.exe versions, My chrome is 60, selenium-standalone is 3.4.0, chromedriver.exe is 2.30

Answer (score 0):

```
 'chromeOptions': {
      'binary': 'D:/chromedriver.exe',
  }
```

The binary should be specify chrome.exe location not webdriver of chrome. please remove the chromeOptions if your chrome browser install in defaul location, otherwise specify the correct path at here.